# Sql query to calculate count of email sent from email open and email bounceback

Tags: sql

[image: As shown in picture against the subject line there is multiple opens and click and from it we have to calculate sends as we are not getting email sents]

So basically i have to calculate sents against subject line , Here is the query i have used:

```
Select distinct SubjectLine
,case when ([Activity]  in ('Click','Opted In','Unsubscribe - All')) then count([EmailAddress]) else 0 end as 'TotalCT'
,case when ([Activity] in ('Click','Opted In','Unsubscribe - All')) then count(distinct[EmailAddress]) else 0 end as 'UniqueCT'
,case when ([Activity] = 'Open')  then count([EmailAddress] ) else 0 end as 'TotalOpens'
,case when ([Activity]  = 'Open')  then count(distinct[EmailAddress]) else 0 end as 'UniqueOpens'
,case when ( [Activity]  = 'Bounceback' ) then count([EmailAddress]) else 0 end as 'Bounces'
,case when ([Activity]  in ('Open','Bounceback'))then count([EmailAddress]) else 0 end as 'Sends'
from  xyz
Group by SubjectLine, Activity
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The question is to calculate email sents .

Comment: Simplify! Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text, (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
Select SubjectLine
       sum(case when [Activity] in ('Click', 'Opted In', 'Unsubscribe - All') then 1 else 0) end as TotalCT,
       sum(case when [Activity] in ('Click', 'Opted In', 'Unsubscribe - All') then 1 else 0 end) as UniqueCT,
       sum(case when [Activity] = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end) as TotalOpens,
       sum(case when [Activity] = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end) as UniqueOpens,
       sum(case when [Activity] = 'Bounceback' then 1 else 0 end) as Bounces,
       sum(case when [Activity] in ('Open', 'Bounceback') then 1 else 0 end) as Sends
from xyz
Group by SubjectLine;
```

Comment: Yes but this wont work i guess how can we apply aggregate over case.

Comment: @AditiSingh . . . I have no idea what your comment means.  Although there might be a syntax error in the answer, the idea definitely works (and there is no obvious syntax error).